# Find file format of loaded bitmap with SkiaSharp?

Tags: skiasharp

I'm trying to figure out the format of an image that is loaded by an array of bytes into an SKBitmap. I'd just like to know if it is a JPEG or PNG, etc.

```
// Was the decoding done by a JPEG decoder or PNG or?
var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(buffer);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would have a look at `SKCodec`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcodec

That doesn't even load the actual image data out the box - just the headers. The way, you don't use stacks of memory when reading the file type.

To read the type, use the `EncodedFormat` property:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcodec.encodedformat

```
using var codec = SKCodec.Create(...);
var format = codec.EncodedFormat;
```

Comment: Even though this `SKCodec` might read only a bit of your stream, it also disposes it ... That's dumb, so you have to make a MemoryStream.